# ReportViewer does not show any results while Sql Server shows results

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, reportviewer

I am using ReportViewer in my project.
When the data range parameter is short it does return results but when the data range is long it shows zero results.

I run the same SQL script in the SQL Server MS. SSMS showing results for any input of the data range parameter.

The returning data is large enough. It is taken more than an hour to generate results for 3-4 months.

How I can solve this issue.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Need a lot more details. What version of report viewer? Local mode or server mode? If server mode does it work directly in ssrs? For either server or local does it work in reportbuilder? Saying "it doesn't work and I'm not going to show you any code at all or give you any details" makes it really hard to help...

Comment: Try to use sql command timeout

Comment: Hi, @dman2306, I am using version 10. It is a local mode and does not work in reportbuilder.

Comment: Hi, @reds, thanks for the suggestion. There is a sql command timeout that is set for 1 minute.

Comment: No problem, I'm just thinking that's just the only way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the sql command timeout into "0" and that solved the problem.